# TypeScript unable to infer type of enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I have two enums that are constructed on each other in the following way:

```
enum COLOR {
    White = '#FFFFFF',
    Black = '#000000',
    SuccessStatusForeground = '#57A300',
    ErrorStatusForeground = '#E00B1C',
}

export enum SemanticColor {
    Default = COLOR.Black,
    DefaultBackground = COLOR.White,
    Success = COLOR.SuccessStatusForeground,
    Error = COLOR.ErrorStatusForeground,
}
```

When I try to pass a style object using `{ backgroundColor: SemanticColor.Success }` I get:

```
 Types of property 'backgroundColor' are incompatible.
    Type 'SemanticColor' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'
```

It looks like TypeScript isn't able to infer that the enum's value is in fact a string.
Any ideas how to solve this one?

Comment: Wow this is bizarre, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40862 and the answer to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64145849/how-can-i-pass-an-enum-with-keys-of-another-string-enum-into-a-function-that-a).  So weird!

Comment: Thanks for this @jcalz! I wasn't able to find it before :)

Comment: @MatanBobi Sorry about [the noise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70885713/438273)! Here's a playground showing the issue in your question: https://tsplay.dev/N9yEVN

Comment: @jsejcksn It's nothing, thanks for your help!